# what is the best way to maintain a list of Transactions in java (transaction object having fields like id, date, amount etc)

Tags: java

What is the best way to maintain a list of Transactions (transaction object having fields like id, date, amount etc) so that i can fetch results based on different criteria like

- last 10 transactions
- transaction between 2 dates
- transactions by year
- etc..

Comment: Sounds like you want a database, or a Map, or a flat CSV file, depending on your needs.

Comment: I would use a lightweight JDBC database such as H2 http://www.h2database.com

Comment: You can literally use a `List` of `Transaction`s, or in Java `List<Transaction>`. The you can use the Stream API (of Java 8) to filter it according to your needs. If you need to store it between runs, take a look at MySQL or SQLite and the ways to acceess it from Java.

Comment: @Peter, yes i am using a Map (Account, list<Transaction>) to store transactions. Now i want to fetch transactions for a particular account based on different criteria.

Comment: You can search through the Transactions using streams and a number of filters.

Comment: Do you use Java 8?

Comment: @Neo, yes i am using java 8

Comment: Depends on how your data is structured.  1.  If you want to query transations between two dates, by year - it would make sense to use a relational database.  The database separates the "data" from your JDBC queries / code.  You can index specific columns data (date, or year).  2.  If your data is not stored in a relational format (primary - foreign key), may look into using a noSQL solution like Redis.  This will allow you to use a Map (Key, Value -> List of transactions).  Regardless of what solution you use, you need think about data structure, backups, and performance (with large volumes).

Answer (score -1):

You can use the Java 8 Stream API.

Say `transactions` is a `List<Transaction>`, you can use, for example:

```
List<Transaction> validTrxs = transactions.stream()
                               .filter( (Transaction tr) -> tr.isValid() )
                               .collect( Collectors.toList() );
```

(Instead of `tr.isValid()` you could put practically any condition you can make into a `boolean` expression)

Comment: The op was asking "What is the best way to maintain a list of Transactions?", not just "here is a stream() -> filter -> collect example".

Comment: @chocksaway The OP already uses a `Map<Account, List<Transaction>>`. What is the question then?

Comment: I am new to java stream API, so not sure on performance of stream filters, if it uses sequential search to filter the result, the complexity would be O(N) and it would not be optimal in case of large number of transactions.

Comment: I think my previous comment (which starts "Depends on how your data is structured") should answer the question @Neo  I have summarised a relational or noSQL solution.  Perhaps the OP can provide more detail about what they are after.  Are you looking for code, storage suggestion, or abit of both :)

Comment: Java Streams can be sequential of parallel.  But, there is a question of (i) performance with large volumes of date (ii) the underlying complexity of streams code (for example in an isValid() method) (iii) how the data is structured.  These three points will dictate how you implement your solution.